# What should I do to restore the calendar when calendar automatically removed?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, display-form

After removing the display form  in the calendar, the calendar automatically removed. What should I do to restore the calendar? I did not create any display form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take the last backup and restore it to a new site collection.
2. Make a granular backup from central admin on the calendar list.
3. Restore the granular backup calendar to your lost calendar.